# asynchronous facebook functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I seem to have some issues with the proper order when javascript functions are complete.
I have a page that checks if a user is logged in to facebook or not. If someone is logged in it will logout that person, and redirect to a different page that contains a like button.
However, when I run the webpage without the redirect the user gets logged out properly. If the redirect is inplace, it no longer forces the logout.

You can test the code on this website: http://quiet-depths-9481.herokuapp.com

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <script src="src/jquery.js"></script>
>   </head>
>   <body style="background-color:#ff6600">
>     <div id="fb-root"></div>
>     <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>       var loggedout = false;
>       window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
>       FB.init({
>       appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
>       channelUrl : '', // Channel File
>       status     : true, // check login status
>       cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
>       xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
>     });
>       fbApiInit = true;
>   }; 
>  (function(d){
>      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
>      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
>      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
>      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=511896318825154";
>      ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
>    }(document));
> ```

```
    function fbEnsureInit(callback) 
   {
      if(!window.fbApiInit) {
          setTimeout(function() {fbEnsureInit(callback);}, 50);
      } else {
          if(callback) {
              callback();
          }
      }
   }

   function fbEnsureLogout(callback) 
   {
      if(!window.loggedout) {
          setTimeout(function() {fbEnsureLogout(callback);}, 50);
      } else {
          if(callback) {
              callback();
          }
      }
   }

   fbEnsureInit(function()
   {
      console.log("this will be run once FB is initialized");
      checkLogout();
   });

   fbEnsureLogout(function()
   {
    console.log("this will run if logout is ensured");
    window.location = "http://quiet-depths-9481.herokuapp.com/like.php"
    document.write('<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/accentjobs" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>');
   });

   function checkLogout()
   {
     console.log('checkLogout');
     FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
     {
       if (response.status === 'connected')          
       {
         var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
         var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
         console.log('logged in & authenticated');
         console.log('trying to logout now.');
         FB.logout(function(response) 
         {  
           console.log('LOGGED OUT!');
           loggedout = true;
         });
       } 
       else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
       {
         console.log('logged in but no authentication');
         console.log('trying to logout now.');
         FB.logout(function(response) 
         {  
           console.log('LOGGED OUT!');
           loggedout = true;
         });
       }
       else
       {
         console.log('Not logged in to facebook!');
         loggedout = true;
       }
     });
   }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you shouldn't be able to logout facebook users without their authentication with your app. You can read this directly in the console, facebook's all.js returns

```
FB.logout() called without an access token.
```

This means, you have to call their api (FB.login or FB.getLoginStatus). Either way, you won't get the access token without proper user authorization with your app/site.

You'll have  to make users login with your app and then sign them out. This probably works for you, because you're app owner so basically you're connected via your app.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, since i cannot force the user to logg off i tried it in a more subtle manner. thanks